# How to get a form value in a controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC. How can I get text box value of the following snippet in my controller method?

```
<form name="forgotpassord" action="forgotpassword" method="POST" >
    <ul>
        <li><label>User:</label> <input type='text' name='j_username' /></li>
        <li><label>&nbsp;</label> <input type="submit" value="OK" class="btn"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `@RequestParam` like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/forgotpassword", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String recoverPass(@RequestParam("j_username") String username) {
    //do smthin
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get single value by **@RequestParam**  and total form values by **@ModelAttribute**.

Here is code for single field-

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/forgotpassword", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String getPassword(@RequestParam("j_username") String username) {
        //your code...
    }
```

And if you have more values in form and want to get all as a single object-
Use **@ModelAttribute** with spring form tag.

Answer (score -2):

```
1. Use Form tag library
Just add 

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<form:form name="forgotpassord" action="forgotpassword" method="POST">
<ul>
    <li><label>User:</label> <input type='text' name='j_username' /></li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;</label> <input type="submit" value="OK" class="btn"></li>
</ul>
</form:form>


2. Now in controller

    @RequestMapping(value="/forgotpassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView forgotpassword(@ModelAttribute("FormJSP_Name") User user,BindingResult result) {

        String user = user.getjUsername(); //use it further
        ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("NextJSP_Name");
        return model1;
    }
```